# it says "to read a single character from user and check whether the character is present in the sentence or not?please help me

Tags: javascript

```
var sentence = window.prompt('Please enter a short sentence describing this      home','');
var character = window.prompt('Please enter a single character','');
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
    if(sentence.charAt(i) == character)
        //  count++;
        document.write('The character' + character + 'is appearing ' + count + 'times in your sentence');
    else 
        document.write('Character not found.Please try again');
```

Comment: `if ( sentence.indexOf(character) != -1 ) alert('tada')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the character and the sentence and then do the following:

```js
var sentence = window.prompt('Please enter a short sentence','');
var character = window.prompt('Please enter a single character','');
var count = 0
for(var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++){
    if(sentence[i] == character){
        count+=1;
      }
  }
if(count > 1){
    alert("The character appeared "+count+" times"); //To fix 'one times'
}else if(count == 1){
    alert("The character appeared 1 time"); //To fix 'one times'
}else{
    alert("The character did not appear in the sentence");
  }
```

First we get the values, and then we loop over `sentence` and for each `character`, if it matches the desired `character`, we add to `count`. Then at the end, if `count` is greater than `0`, we alert the amount of times, and if it *is* `0`, we alert that it was not in the sentence.

Comment: actually i am soo sorry to say but its not working again

Comment: it is not showing me the number of characters appeared or not

Comment: @AyeshaAslam whats your error?

Comment: @AyeshaAslam if the character doesn't appear, it alerts `"The character did not appear in the sentence"`, not `0`.

Comment: its like first output window first ask me to write sentence, then character and after that nothing appears..like after it, it should appear that the character appearing or not..but i am not getting any such output window :(

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there!

There are actually many, *many* ways to do this; using built-in methods, it's as easy as

```
if (sentence.indexOf(character) == -1)
  document.write('The character does not appear at all within the sentence.';
```

But, if you would like to count, as you have in your provided example, you just need

```
var sentence = window.prompt('Please enter a short sentence','');
var character = window.prompt('Please enter a single character','');

var count = 0;
for (var i=0; i<sentence.length; i++){
  count += (sentence[i] == character);
}
if (count > 0){
  document.write("The character appeared " + count + " times.");
} else {
  document.write("The character did not appear in the sentence");
}
```

Basically, you only increment count within the loop, when a character matches, and you check if there were any outside.

Comment: Congrats on 2k rep bro